# Поиск окна по имени и классу

Tags: windows, winapi

Подскажите, существуют ли в WinAPI функции для поиска определенного окна, если известны его имя и класс, и передачи найденному окну фокуса(выводу его поверх остальных окон)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, для поиска правильнее было бы воспользоваться функцией [FindWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633500(VS.85).aspx) c более широкими возможностями. А для отображения окна поверх остальных функцией [SetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633539.aspx).

Comment: FindWindowsEx избыточна в большинстве случаев, но конечно можно. А SetForegroundWindow имеет довольно много ограничений и на практике редко когда помогает.

Answer (score 1):

Для поиска можно воспользоваться FindWindow, а для установки его поверх всех остальных SetWindowPos - во втором параметре укажите HWND_TOP.